# Git diff creating empty patch when using external difftool

Tags: git, diff, patch

I'm trying to create a diff file (patch) between two commits.  I'm trying the command

`git diff 62fe9db 7661a06 > ~/Desktop/patch`

but the file created is empty.  When I run the above command, since I'm using p4merge as my external diff tool, p4merge opens and shows me the diffs.  But after closing p4merge, I find that the patch file is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for creating a patch using git is `git diff -p <commit> <commit>`.

The `git --help diff` documentation has an option that will cut out the external diffing tool -

```
--no-ext-diff
    Disallow external diff drivers.
```

That may fix your issue.